# Kotlin error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

Tags: kotlin

I'm about the lose my mind.
With another language it would take my 2 minutes but i'm newbie at Kotlin. and i'm struggeling to write a single update api.
requirment is simple i will take search name as parameter, go through the user's list. and update the search in user's list. then return the updated search.

```
@DeleteMapping("{favoriteSearchName}")
fun deleteFavoriteSearch(@PathVariable favoriteSearchName: String): Api.FavoriteSearch{
    val lastUsed: DateTime = DateTime(Date())
    getUser().favoriteSearches?.find { it.searchName == favoriteSearchName  }?.lastUsed =lastUsed ?.userRepository.save(getUser())
            ?.toApi()
            ?: throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
}
```

but this code returns

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor DateTime(p0: Date!) defined in com.google.api.client.util.DateTime
public constructor DateTime(p0: Long) defined in com.google.api.client.util.DateTime
public constructor DateTime(p0: String!) defined in com.google.api.client.util.DateTime
```

why can't i update the field here?

Comment: Check your imports. You may have imported the wrong type of Date class for what the Google DateTime constructor takes as a parameter. By the way, throwing an exception for something that is not a programming error is considered bad form in Kotlin: https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07

Comment: Looks like the `Date()` that you're trying to pass into the `DateTime` constructor is not the correct version of `Date`. Is it possible that you're not importing the right `Date`?